# "Could not find a required file. remote: Name: index.html" This the error I get whenever I deploy my ReactJS app via Heroku, Zeit/Now or Netlify

Tags: reactjs, heroku, web-deployment, netlify, zeit-pkg

I created my react app with the create-react-app utility which places the index.html file in the public folder by default. I have not moved it from there and it is the exact same way in the repo [link to the public folder](https://github.com/quonn-bernard/react-redux-cart/tree/master/react-cart/public). I've already checked my .gitignore to make sure it isn't ignoring index.html. I've run npm install to make sure all dependencies are in place. Here is my current directory structure. Not sure what the issue is and have tried all suggested troubleshooting methods.

[image]

Here is my directory structure

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to move your public folder to the route path of the project outside of the current directory